# Get userdata inside custom build plugin

Tags: plugins

So I am working on a custom plugin which will get the option to set Roles & Capabilities per user to enable/disable certain pages/parts inside the plugin. So I wanted the get the logged in users roles value by using `get_userdata()`but this trows in an error `Call to undefined function get_userdata()`, I have seen that this is an common issue but I haven't found any solution for this.

So how do I get the user data inside a plugin?

Comment: can you post the code ? `get_userdata()` is a valid function, but it's plug-able function which can be altered. So, you just can not call it as we can `add_action()` without awaiting for any hook to be loaded. You just need to make sure `plugins_loaded` hook is fired before you are calling `get_userdata()`.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 reasons why `get_userdata` fails and both are related to the fact that it is a [**pluggable function**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions).

Pluggable functions can be overriden by plugins, so if a plugin override that function, and the plugin is poorly coded, that function can fail. However this is **not** the most common reason why using that function cause an error.

The reason why it happen, often is that is used in a wrong way.

Pluggable function are defined in the `pluggable.php` that is loaded **after** all the plugins are loaded, otherwise is impossible for plugins override functions in it.

So, if in a plugin you use that function without wrapping it in a proper hook, the function is not defined, and so the error.

You can solve the problem in 2 ways:

### 1. Wrap the function in a proper hook

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {

  // stuff here where you get user id

  $user_data = get_userdata( $userid );

  // stuff here

});
```

The first hook you can use is `'plugins_loaded'` but if you want **to get info of current logged in user you should use `'wp_loaded'` hook**.

### 2. Don't use pluggable functions

What `get_userdata` do, is just return an instance of `WP_User` that has the id you pass as argument. So, if you can use:

```
// stuff here where you get user id

$user_data = FALSE;
$data = WP_User::get_data_by( 'id', $userid );
if ( ! empty($data) ) {
  $user = new WP_User;
  $user_data = $user->init( $data );
}
```

and that is exactly the same of `$user_data = get_userdata( $userid );`.
This code work without wrapping it in hook, because `WP_User` class is defined in [`'wp-includes/capabilites.php'`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L406) file that is loaded very early.

However, is considered a good practice write code in plugin wrapping it in predictable hooks, so first solution is better.

If you want, you can use the best of both solutions, using a proper hook and avoid using a pluggable function that can be overridden by others plugins:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function() {

  // stuff here where you get user id

  $user_data = FALSE;
  $data = WP_User::get_data_by( 'id', $userid );
  if ( ! empty($data) ) {
    $user = new WP_User;
    $user_data = $user->init( $data );
  }

  // stuff here

});
```

Probably this is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks but when I do use this I get this error 'Missing argument 2 for WP_User::get_data_by()'

Comment: I found another solution that will do the trick global $current_user; echo $current_user->roles;

Comment: @user759235 there was a little error on my code, I fixed it now. Sure, `global $current_user` may work, however you need to wait for `'wp_loaded'` hook (or `'init'` hook with a priority > 10). In addition, relying on global variables is never a good idea when you can avoid it. Look at [`wp_get_current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) function, instead.

Comment: How do I get the $userid inside that class to work?

Comment: @user759235 I answered [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134826/trying-to-get-logged-in-user-data-inside-php-class/134834#134834)