# Trying to get logged-in user data inside php class

Tags: plugins, oop

I am trying to get the current logged-in user data and use this in the parent class(I need it in several functions).

In the example below I can get the userID in the first function but it will give no output inside the next function.

This is my first wordpress plugin and the first time that I work with OOP, so who can help me out with this thing.

```
<?php

class WP_PM{

    public $currentId;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->addActions();
        $this->showId();
    }

    private function addActions(){
        add_action('wp_loaded', array(&$this, 'getId'));
    }

    public function getId(){
        global $current_user;

        $this->currentId = $current_user->ID;

        //$this->currentId = 'hello';//we have an output

        echo $this->currentId;//we have an output

        return $this->currentId;
    }

    public function showId(){
        echo $this->currentId;//no output
            echo $this->getId();//no output
    }

}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('WP_PM', 'activate'));
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('WP_PM', 'deactivate'));

$wp_pm = new WP_PM();
?>
```

// new example based on G.M solution(still not working -> triggers wp error and no logged in text)

```
class WP_PM_Extend extends WP_User {

    function getID() {
        return $this->ID;
    }

}

class WP_PM{

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(WP_PM_Extend $user = NULL){

        if (!is_null( $user ) && $user->exists()){
            $this->user = $user;
        }

        $this->getUser();

    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

}


function getWPPM() {

    if(!did_action('wp_loaded')){
     $msg = 'Please call getCurrentUser after wp_loaded is fired.';
    return new WP_Error('to_early_for_user', $msg);
    }

    static $wp_powertour_core = NULL;

    if(is_null( $wp_powertour_core)){
        $wp_pM = new WP_PM( new WP_PM_Extend( get_current_user_id() ) );
    }

    return $wp_powertour_core;
}

function getCurrentUser(){

  $wppm = getWPPM();

    if(is_wp_error($wppm)){
        return $wppm;
     }

    $user = $wppm->getUser();

    if($user instanceof WP_PM_Extend){ 
        return $user;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'getCurrentUser');

$current_user = getCurrentUser();
if($current_user instanceof WP_PM_Extend){
    echo 'Current user ID: ' . $current_user->getID();
}else{
    echo 'No one logged in';
}
```

Comment: I see lots of problems.  I am going to tackle the constructor.  Plugins are loaded very early, before a user is authenticated.  Calling showId() (in constructor) which tries to print out current_user info wont work.  getId() works because it is called at 'wp_loaded' which is after the user authentication process. Note that printing out information in the plugin could disrupt WP by interferring its normal output... for example if WP or plugin tries to update http headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you said is you first time using OOP, I want to say: stop using `&` before `$this`: PHP4 died long time ago.

Second tip, don't use global variables, if you can. I know that function like `wp_get_current_user` use global variable internally, but I hope that in future it will not be so anymore, however not seeing that `global` word in my code, make me fill a little better.

Third tip, try to make your plguin more solid using type hinting.

Here I post how I had wrote that code.

Firts of all I'd wrote 2 classes, probably in 2 different files named in same way of class:

```
class WP_PM_User extends WP_User {

  function getID() {
    return $this->ID;
  }

}

class WP_PM {

  protected $user;

  function __construct ( WP_PM_User $user = NULL) {
    if ( ! is_null( $user ) && $user->exists() ) $this->user = $user;
  }

  function getUser() {
    return $this->user;
  }

}
```

After that, somewhere in plugin (maybe in main plugin file) I'd write two function like this:

```
function getWPPM() {

  if ( ! did_action('wp_loaded') ) {
    $msg = 'Please call getCurrentUser after wp_loaded is fired.';
    return new WP_Error( 'to_early_for_user', $msg );
  }

  static $wp_pm = NULL;

  if ( is_null( $wp_pm ) ) {
    $wp_pm = new WP_PM( new WP_PM_User( get_current_user_id() ) );
  }

  return $wp_pm;
}


function getCurrentUser() {

  $wppm = getWPPM();

  if ( is_wp_error( $wppm ) ) return $wppm;

  $user = $wppm->getUser();

  if ( $user instanceof WP_PM_User ) return $user;
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'getCurrentUser' );
```

Doing so, everywhere in your plugin you can call `getCurrentUser` and retrieve the current user object, and if you want the ID, you can call `getID()` on the user returned by `getCurrentUser`.

Usage example:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {

  $current_user = getCurrentUser();
  if ( $current_user instanceof WP_PM_User ) {
    echo 'Current user ID: ' . $current_user->getID();
  } else {
    echo 'No one logged in';
  }

}, 30 );
```

Comment: not sure if it's me but I copyed your code but i get an error     <pre><code>Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'getCurrentUser' not found or invalid function name in xxxxxxxx\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 429</code></pre>

Comment: the error was my fault, I forgot the add the add_option, but some reason the class is called twice, showing all of the code twice. I have added your example to top post.

Comment: Okay so I couldn't find the issue last night but I have found the error you forgot to use of 'this' getCurrentUser() should be $this->getCurrentUser()....but no the example echo's out the 'o one logged in'..

Comment: Yes I now see why I need the this, as I am using the code inside the Class, I dont want to use any thing outside my classes.

Comment: The code outside the class is used to to the work inside the class only once. It allows you to have only one instance of `WP_PM` instance and so to be sure that the `WP_PM_User` instance you get is always the same instance. Having different instances and checking the roles should work, but if you set some properties on an instance when you get again the property will be not setted.

Comment: I have update my example above(bases on your help) and all goes well, but it will trigger the WP_Error and it will show the 'no one logged in' text

Comment: Okay got it working now many thanks. Dont want to nag but isn't there a way to do this all inside a class rather adding code outside the class?

Comment: @user759235 as asid before, all the work is done inside the class. Code out of class is the to *use* the class. You can use only the class code, but many depends on how your plugin should work...

Answer (score 0):

You are firing both `$this->getId();` and `$this->showId();` in the constructor. I am pretty sure that that is the problem.

If this is a plugin, which it looks like it is since you are using activation hooks, you should be able to do this:

```
public function getId(){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $this->currentId = $current_user->ID;

    //$this->currentId = 'hello';//we have an output

    echo $this->currentId;//we have an output

    return $this->currentId;
}
```

And have things work after that.

If you instantiate in other contexts, you need to be careful what hook it instantiates on. Too early and neither `$current_user` nor `get_currentuserinfo()` will be defined.

For example,

```
add_action(
  'muplugins_loaded',
  function() {
    global $wp_pm;
    $wp_pm = new WP_PM();
  }
);
```

... will give you a notice about an undefined function-- `get_currentuserinfo()`.

Comment: the getId should not be in the constuctor thats right(not present in the real example). But I still dont get an output in the other function...

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely loading your class instance early.

First solution could be loading the class this way -

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_wp_pm' );
function load_wp_pm(){
    global $wp_pm;
    $wp_pm = new WP_PM();
}
```

Another way it can be accomplished by modifying `__contruct` and adding another method -

```
// modified the construct method
public function __construct(){
    add_action( 'init', array( get_class(), '_init' ) );
}

// getting user id & setting the $currentId variable and 
public function _init(){
    $this->addActions();
    $this->showId();
}
```

This would probably show you some output.