# Call to undefined function get_userdata in user.php

Tags: plugins, errors, pluggable

My website error log is full of

```
[lsapi:error] [...] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  
Call to undefined function get_userdata() 
in /home/.../public_html/wp-includes/user.php on line 460
```

... and the site does not load (blank page, no source).
The only changes that were recently made are Wordpress and plugin updates (I don't know which ones and when); no programming of any kind.

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134798/73605) made me suspect that a plugin did override `get_userdata`, but a recursive search for `function get_userdata` in the `wp-content\plugins` folder (after downloading the entire site through FTP) finds nothing (even a manual inspection for all instances of `get_userdata` finds only function calls, no definitions).

`wp_settings.php` seems OK, relevant part:

```
// Load active plugins.
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() as $plugin ) {
    wp_register_plugin_realpath( $plugin );
    include_once( $plugin );
}
unset( $plugin );

// Load pluggable functions.
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable-deprecated.php' );

// Set internal encoding.
wp_set_internal_encoding();
```

Maybe I can use [this 7 year old hack](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-custom-upload-dir-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get_userdata/) in `user.php`, but that looks weird. Why would I have to patch Wordpress files?

Of course, my primary suspects are still the plugins. I selectively disabled all plugins with [this trick](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/), renaming the plugin folder names.

Then, after renaming them back, **the site was suddenly accessible again**, so was the WP login.

These plugin folder names were:

```
admin-language
akismet
backupwordpress
broken-link-checker
contact-form-7
flatbook-custom-posts
google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp
gravityforms
mollie-forms
pronamic-ideal
```

**Update** Of course the site 'suddenly' worked: I notice in the control panel that all plugins are deactivated (the text *Activate* is available).

If I now activate *Gravityforms*, the site hangs again. So I know this is the culprit, but where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was a plugin after all. Since several activated plugins seemed to trigger the error, I thought *What is a common plugin here?*

It turns out that [admin-language](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-language/) was the culprit. With hindsight, that may no be a surprise: that page says:

> This plugin hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.